# PHP - Convert long float to decimal

Tags: php, floating-point

I got a float like this 1.17753e27 and want to convert it to a decimal number like 1.3243242

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$var = '122.34343The';
$float_value_of_var = floatval($var);
echo $float_value_of_var; // 122.34343
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
float round ( float $val [, int $precision = 5 [, int $mode = PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP ]] )
```

Comment: Yeah and that still prints 1.17753E+27. I thought it's obvious that I don't want something like E+27 in the result. Sorry if I wasn't clear about that.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code to convert long float to decimal
`float floor ( float $value )`